# Как подключить curl к проекту

Tags: c++, curl, visual-studio-2019

Здравствуйте я не совсем понимаю каким образом нужно подключать curl откуда скачивать и т.д
Насколько я понял в проекте нужно включить `curl.h` и `libcurl.lib` но когда я скачиваю curl https://curl.se/windows/ там нет `libcurl.lib` поэтому я не понимаю я что-то не то скачиваю или где-то не там ищу `libcurl.lib`. Поэтому возник у меня вопрос откуда нужно скачать `curl` и что подключить что-бы он заработал в проекте

Comment: curl.h и libcurl.lib можно получить скачав исходники и самостоятельно собрав библиотеку с настройками, совместимыми с настройками вашего проекта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

по указанной ссылке можно скачать прекомпилированные файлы для mingw, для студии надо поискать самостоятельно или воспользоваться инструкцией и собрать самому https://curl.se/mail/lib-2009-04/att-0198/visual_studio_libcurl.pdf

- Загрузите по ссылке https://curl.haxx.se/download.html.
- Распакуйте и откройте проект projects\Windows\VC15\curl-all.sln.
- Выберите конфигурацию LIB Release - DLL Windows SSPI и LIB Debug - DLL Windows SSPI для нужных целей (Win32 и x64)
- скопируйте build\lib\x86\ (или build\lib\x64) в свой каталог файлы libcurld.lib (для дебага) и libcurl.lib релиз

Answer (score 0):

Установите себе `vcpkg` (https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg) и скачивайте через него.

```
vcpkg install curl
```

Потом вам желательно использовать `cmake`, потому что он прекрасно интегрируется с `vcpkg`